# Is it possible to copy files from a UNC source to a webDav destination with a script?

Tags: asp.net, vbscript, asp-classic, webdav

I work in a very large, complex Intranet environment. I have run into a very unique issue that I cannot seem to resolve.

**Forwarning**

The technologies I mention are very outdated and that is the way is has to stay. I work in a very large enterprise and they have a ton of legacy things in place. I normally work on the modern side of things, but this got placed in my lap.

**The problem:**

We have a file located on our IIS 7.x server with path \serverName\shareName\wwwroot\myfile.jpg. I need to copy this file to a webDav location of a DIFFERENT web server using ASP , vbscript, or another similar web technology. For a multitude of security implications, I don't have access to the webDav UNC path, only the http: path. I am able to map this drive and access the http: location using windows explorer. I can even manually copy files, create files, and delete them. However, when I try to use a script, I get no where.

I am not great with vbscript so bare with my attempts:

**Attempt 1:**

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
strCommand = oShell.Run("Xcopy ""sourceLocation"" ""destination location"" /S /Y", 0, True) 

If strCommand <> 0 Then 
MsgBox "File Copy Error: " & strCommand 
Else 
MsgBox "Done" 

End If
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
<%

dim objFSOpublish
set objFSOpublish = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strCurrentUNCfull = "sourcePath"
mPublishPath = "destinationPath"

objFSOpublish.CopyFile strCurrentUNCfull, mPublishPath 


set objFSOpublish = nothing

%>
```

I have no idea if this is even possible to do without the webDav UNC path because I don't have much experience with webDav. If it is possible I have exhausted my limited knowledge in this space and need help badly. I scoured Google tirelessly trying to find a similar issue to no avail. Any and all help or direction will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to do something like this:

```
On Error Resume Next

sUrl = "YourURLHere"
sFile = "UNCPathToYourFile"

'Here we are just reading your file into an ODB
'stream so we can manipulate it
Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
oStream.Mode = 3
oStream.Type = 1
oStream.Open
oStream.LoadFromFile(sFile)

'Here we are doing the upload of the oStream
'object we just created.
Set oHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
oHTTP.Open "POST", sUrl, False
oHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-Length", oStream.Size
oHTTP.Send oStream.Read(oStream.Size)

'Check for errors.
If Err = 0 Then
  Wscript.Echo oHTTP.responseText 
Else
  Wscript.Echo "Upload Error!" & vbCrLf & Err.Description
End If

'Optionally close out our objects
oStream.Close
Set oStream = Nothing
Set oHTTP = Nothing
```

Comment: +1 I was going to do answer something similar, but using "PUT"

Comment: I tried to implement this and nothing happened. I didn't receive an error of any kind, but the file isn't present in the destination location either. To make sure I am clear, I placed the webdav url in the sURL location and I placed the UNC path of the file I want to copy in the sFile location. Right?

Comment: Comment the "On Error Resume Next" out and see if there is an error being thrown.

Comment: After commenting "On Error Resume Next" out I receive the following error: Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8' 

Object required: '' 
The line it refers to contains   Wscript.Echo oHTTP.responseText. However, if the script is getting that far, shouldn't the file be in the new location?

Comment: That's pretty strange. You shouldn't be getting Object required because the oHTTP object is obviously created successfully. If you're using the code above I can't see why that'd happen. Perhaps you can paste the actual code you're using and the actual line number?

Comment: Sure thing. I really appreciate all of the time you have spent on this.

Comment: I posted the code im using as an answer because of it's length.

Comment: You want to change this line: Set oHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP"), notice I added "Server" to the CreateObject line.

Comment: Unfortunately I am still getting the same error on the same line.

Comment: Do a Response.Write oStream.Size & " bytes <br>" after you've created the oStream object. Does it display the correct size of the file?

Comment: It does write the correct size to the page. Then the error follows that.

Comment: According to this you can just use FSO and oFSO.Copy to the UNC of the server, is that true?

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/0a13f745-6217-4575-a231-3336716cb529/copy-a-file-to-library-with-vbscript?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I am currently using with the actual file path redacted. Let me know if you see anything that is incorrect.

**The page is saved as a .ASP.**

```
<%
sUrl = "http://server.site.com:80/subDomain/wwwroot/"
sFile = "\\server\developmentShare\wwwroot\page.htm"

'Here we are just reading your file into an ODB
'stream so we can manipulate it
Set oStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
oStream.Mode = 3
oStream.Type = 1
oStream.Open
oStream.LoadFromFile(sFile)


'Here we are doing the upload of the oStream
'object we just created.
Set oHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
oHTTP.Open "POST", sUrl, False
oHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-Length", oStream.Size
oHTTP.Send oStream.Read(oStream.Size)

'Check for errors.
If Err = 0 Then

Wscript.Echo oHTTP.responseText 
 Else
Wscript.Echo "Upload Error!" & vbCrLf & Err.Description
 End If

'Optionally close out our objects
oStream.Close
Set oStream = Nothing
Set oHTTP = Nothing

%>
```